# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str | Django | React | Postman

Tags: python, django, postman

> When using POST on postman it comes back with TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. If I POST from client side(react) I get a network error **'int' object is not iterable**

```
PostMan POST:
    [
 {
    "time": "2019-12-12",
    "user": 1,
    "title": "Test123",
    "description": "Nice!",
    "photo": "http://localhost:8000/asd",
    "activity": [{"name": "hike"}, {"name": "swimming"}]
}
```

]

```
> File "/Users/michaelchisholm/capstone-end/server/vacaplusapi/views/location.py",line 26, in create
> user=user, title=data["title"], time=data["time"], description=data["description"], photo=data["photo"] 
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> "POST /locations HTTP/1.1" 500 89394
```

Django view Location CREATE

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        location = Location.objects.all()
        return location

    def create(self, request):
        """Handle Location operations for categories"""
        

        data = request.data
        user = VacaUser.objects.get(user=request.auth.user)
        

        new_location = Location.objects.create(
            user=user, title=data["title"], time=data["time"], description=data["description"], photo=data["photo"]
        )

        new_location.save()

        for activity in data["activity"]:
            activity_obj = Activity.objects.get(activity_name=activity["activity"])
            new_location.activity.add(activity_obj)

        serializer = LocationSerializer(new_location, context={'request': request})

        try:
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except ValidationError as ex:
            return Response({"reason": ex.message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> this is what data =

```
    [{'time': '2019-12-12', 'user': 1, 'title': 'Test123', 'description': 'Nice!', 'photo': 'http://localhost:8000/asd',
> 'activity': [{'name': 'hike'}, {'name': 'swimming'}]}]
```

Comment: From that error message, it looks like `data` is a list, but you were expecting it to be a dictionary.

Comment: Can you print `data` to see what it is?

Comment: [{'time': '2019-12-12', 'user': 1, 'title': 'Test123', 'description': 'Nice!', 'photo': 'http://localhost:8000/asd', 'activity': [{'name': 'hike'}, {'name': 'swimming'}]}].    I did a POST request with the same data above to trigger logging.debug(data)

Comment: Yes, that's a list.  (It has `[]` on the outer edges.)

Comment: I see that your PostMan POST example also starts with `[` and ends with `]`, so that's probably why.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Totally passed over and it and didn't even think about it.